# loss function is returning nan tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've written a simple tensorflow program here that reads in a feature list and tries to predict the class.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in range (hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            itere = int(X_train.shape[0]/batch_size)
            last = 0
            add = 1
            for start in range(itere):
                x_train_epoch = X_train[last: ((start + add) * batch_size),:]
                y_train_epoch = y_1Hot_train.eval()[last: ((start + add) * batch_size),:]
#                 print("shape of x", x_train_epoch.shape, "shape of y", y_train_epoch.shape)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: x_train_epoch, y: y_train_epoch})
                epoch_loss += c
                last = start * batch_size
                add = 0
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss', epoch_loss )
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval( {x: X_test, y: y_1Hot_test.eval() }))
```

Link: https://gist.github.com/makark/79af6ca53ca27d51abb1d87c9b9bac07

Data file: https://gist.github.com/makark/eb859f50237edb9343f3ca32aeb3be2b

However, when I run my code I keep getting a loss of "nan". I'm not sure what is going on... any help would be much appreciated!

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-149-0164f4af7d52>:46: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
Epoch 0 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 1 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 2 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 3 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 4 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 5 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 6 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 7 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 8 completed out of 10 loss nan
Epoch 9 completed out of 10 loss nan
Accuracy: 0.589097
```

Comment: Please write your code (the relevant parts of it) instead of providing a link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the inputs have nan's, fix it by `X[np.isnan(X)] = 0`.
- the inputs are not scaled, use sklearn's `StandardScaler` to normalize your inputs.
- Set the weights to a small initial value use stddev in random_normal.
- Fix the bug in calculation of output: `output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']),output_layer['biases'] )` .

Comment: Thank you so much! These steps made my accuracy increase from 58.4% to 71.5%! Would you have any other suggestions to further improve accuracy?

Comment: update your code in the above link, i can have a look.

Comment: Hi Vijay, I was wondering if you had a chance to look at the new code? Doing small tweaks here and there has got me to a maximum of 76% accuracy but not able to go any higher since then... Would love to get your thoughts.

Comment: Even i got around 75% , i think you need to check your input features, and see whether you can improve them.