# How to check the predicted output of a trained Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

I am working with this code

https://medium.com/@curiousily/tensorflow-for-hackers-part-ii-building-simple-neural-network-2d6779d2f91b

I don't have any issues with this code. My question is :

How do I predict the output of the trained network? I have tried with the command

```
pred_NN = predictions.eval(feed_dict = {x: x_test,keep_prob: 1})
```

but it returns,

```
       [nan, nan],
       ..........
       [nan, nan]], dtype=float32)`
```

Answer (score 0):

([loss function is returning nan tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023124/loss-function-is-returning-nan-tensorflow)) has some answers. Reducing the learning rate to prevent in from converting to infinity might also help.

Comment: I am getting 'nan'. My question is how to get rid of this 'nan'. I want to see the predicted output by the trained NN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023124/loss-function-is-returning-nan-tensorflow might help. Also try reducing the learning rate.